# Cycle over arrays of different sizes using iterators in Rust

Tags: rust, iterator, cycle

I have a vector containing two vectors of different sizes:

```rust
let vectors = vec![
    vec![0, 1],
    vec![2, 3, 4]
];
```

I would like to create an iterator to cycle over the elements of each vector, returning:

```
0: [0, 2]
1: [1, 3]
2: [0, 4]
3: [1, 2]
...
```

In this example there are two vectors, but I would like to generalize this for k vectors.

I have tried this:

```rust
let cycles = vectors
    .into_iter()
    .map(|x| x.into_iter().cycle());

loop {
    let output: Vec<_> = cycles
        .map(|x| x.next().unwrap())
        .collect();
}
```

However, it does not work, because `x` cannot be borrowed as mutable.

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `x` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:14:22
   |
14 |             .map(|x| x.next().unwrap())
   |                   -  ^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
   |                   |
   |                   help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut x`
```

I understand the error, but I fail to think of an alternative way to build this iterator. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=629098622e9d3768a1829bbf5ecd554a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to collect the iterators into some datastructure like `Vec`.

You can then use `iter_mut` to iterate over mutable references which let you advance the collected iterators.

```rust
fn main() {
    let vectors = vec![vec![0, 1], vec![2, 3, 4]];
    let mut cycles = vectors
        .into_iter()
        .map(|x| x.into_iter().cycle())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    for i in 0.. {
        let output: Vec<_> = cycles.iter_mut().map(|x| x.next().unwrap()).collect();
        println!("{i}: {output:?}");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have beat me by 7 seconds :)

Comment: :D Jinx!! @bddap

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I will accept this first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
0: [0, 2]
1: [1, 3]
2: [0, 4]
3: [1, 2] <- was 3
...
```

If so:

```rust
let vectors: Vec<Vec<u8>> = vec![vec![0, 1], vec![2, 3, 4]];
let mut cycles: Vec<_> = vectors.iter().map(|x| x.iter().cycle()).collect();

for i in 0..4 {
    let output: Vec<_> = cycles.iter_mut().map(|x| x.next().unwrap()).collect();
    println!("{i}: {output:?}");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I meant that! Thanks!